# Why is XF86LogGrabInfo not resulting in debug output in Xorg log?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, 18.04

Last year I [found a way](https://askubuntu.com/q/925732/165026) to debug what is capturing keyboard shortcuts, by sending X events using `xdotool`. Now, I have a similar problem where using the Ctrl-Alt-Left in IntelliJ isn't doing anything, so I suspect something is holding on to it.

This time, though, nothing is printing in the logs!

I also tried with other keycombos that were global (such as Win+a, which opens the applications menu), but they produced no log entries either.

What has changed from Ubuntu 17.04 to 18.04 that disables the log output, and how can I enable the log output? There are other entries in the logs, mind you :)

You can try out my debugging steps [using this gist](https://gist.github.com/fatso83/2370679439479dcc27eb602e8ce6b3de), like this:

`~/bin/debug-x-shortcut  Super_R+a`

Comment: Same problem with Ctrl+Alt+Left. I see the dump in .local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log however I cannot find an offending app.

Comment: Any progress on this? In my case your debug script output look like this https://gist.github.com/gregd/b63769bbf5c2ca0695c6e024c91f8f94

Comment: Sorry, but no. Haven't looked since posting, though. Might need to check with official Ubuntu forums/bug trackers, but not sure what "the bug" is.